# Prove that there does not exists RATIONAL numbers $x$ and $y$ such that $x^2 - y^2 = 1002$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I tried to prove this using contradiction.

Suppose there does exists rationals $x$ and $y$ such that $x^2 - y^2 = 1002$

Let $ x = a/b  $ and $y = c/d$

Irreducible fractions.

I come up with $$ (ad)^2 - (bc)^2 = 1002 \cdot (bd)^2 $$

Thus

$$ (ad)^2 = (cb)^2 \pmod{1002}$$

And i'm stuck on this

Any tip or hint?

Thanks

This problem appears in the first chapter 'Contemporary Abstract Algebra"

Comment: Hint:  you'd have $(x-y)(x+y)=1002$.  Think about parity.

Comment: @lulu I think $x$ and $y$ are rational, not necessarily integers.

Comment: Do you mean rationals or integers $x,y$? $\displaystyle\left(\frac{503}2\right)^2-\left(\frac{499}2\right)^2=1002$.

Comment: The book says rationals, weird.

Comment: @alex.jordan  Oh, but it is obviously false for rationals.  Take any two rationals that multiply to $1002$ and solve for $x,y$.

Comment: @lulu Indeed - applying to $1\times n$ gives $\left(\frac{n+1}2\right)^2-\left(\frac{n-1}2\right)^2=n$

Comment: It appears that the author made a mistake, thank you all.

Comment: Found the book online https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0ahUKEwiwmduWiYPYAhWd3oMKHfZGAmAQFgg4MAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fisidore.co%2Fcalibre%2Fget%2Fpdf%2F4975&usg=AOvVaw3r6cIB7rR3eqAWMpdjrHUJ but could not find the problem.

Comment: @fleablood It's the ninth edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $(x^2 - y^2) = 1002$

$(x + y)(x - y) = 1002$

Let $x + y = 2$ and $x - y = 501$

Solve for $x,y$.   $x =\frac {503}2$ and $y = - \frac {499}{2}$.

That's a solution.  $\frac {503^2}4 - \frac {499^2}{4} = \frac {253009-249001}4=\frac {4008}{4 }= 1002$.

So not true.

Now if $x$ and $y$ must be *integers*..

We have $(x+y)(x-y) = 2*3*167$.

$(x + y) + (x-y) = 2x$ so $x+y$ and $x-y$ must both be odd or both be even.  But $2$ must divide one but only one of $x+y$ or $x-y$.

Answer (score 0):

On rational number you can certainly find solutions.

On integer note that:

$$x^2 - y^2 = (x+y)(x-y)=1002=501\cdot 2$$
Since $x+y$ and $x-y$ have the same parity there not exists any solution (in the factorization 2 should compare with exponent 0 or even).